# Update a single BLOB column for a specific row with a Null or any other value using a sql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, database, delphi, blob

I have 2 identical tables (both column count, name and settings).
I have 1 identical row on each table, identical information.
One of the columns is a `BLOB` type column and contains an Image (bmp).

Both rows / tables have an `id` column, `auto increment`, so id's are identical for every row in both tables.
The column set to `blob` type CAN be `NULL` (it's set).

I'm using an `action` that has the following query's:

```
dbmodule.arhivaQuery.SQL.Clear;
dbmodule.arhivaQuery.SQL.Add('UPDATE `database_name`.`2nd_table_name` SET `column_name`=deleted WHERE `id`=''' + inttostr(dbmodule.comenziDataSetid.Value) + ''';');
dbmodule.arhivaQuery.ExecSql(true);
```

This should theoretically update the row in the 2nd table by removing the bmp from the blob column, or rather, replacing the bmp with the word "deleted". It doesn't, the image is still in the column / row.

A few things to clarify:

dbmodule is the name of a data module that contains the dataset, data source, sql connection and query. (`TSimpleDataSet`, `TDataSource`, `TSQLConnection`, `TSQLQuery`).

arhivaQuery is the name of the query I'm using (a `TSQLQuery`)
column_name = name of the column, I've edited in this paste so you can get a clearer picture.

You notice at the end I use the id of the row from the 1st table to change the data in the 2nd, so that's why that is there (ids are identical for the row in both tables).

When I execute this it should keep both rows in both tables but update just the row in the 2nd table by removing its image from the blob column.
So after this I should have `row` in 1st `table` with the image in the blob column and same row in the 2nd table with no image in the blob column.

I'm guessing my sql syntax is wrong (got some warnings saying so too), can anyone correct it for me please?

Comment: My quess is *deleted* has to have some kind of quote mark around it to indicate it is a string.

Comment: Thought so too, I've tried the following: `deleted` 'deleted' (deleted) (`deleted`) ('deleted') - none work. All of them return an error from either delphi or the software saying to check my syntax (delphi says it expected either : or ; or ) - can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Use double ' to escape one in Delphi code (`' ... =''deleted'' WHERE ... '`).

Comment: No more error in Delphi using that but it still doesn't modify the cell for that row in my 2nd table.

Comment: If you want to clear the blob field, assign it the value `NULL`. Also, *stop concatenating your SQL* and use parameters, and you won't have to worry about double/triple/quadruple quotes. And *I'm guessing my syntax is wrong (got some warnings saying so too)* is useless - if you got syntax errors, *why are they not included in your post*? They're on the screen right in front of you, and they can easily be copied and pasted into your post. Error messages are relevant information, and you should include the relevant information in your question for us to use as well.

Comment: What's the sql syntax to assign null value for that cell? Can you show me a specific example for my case so I can understand? I've set the column to be null if need be so I can insert null values, just need to see the syntax I should be using, so I can understand.

Comment: Yes. `SET columname = NULL`. Using parameters, you just say `ParamByName('parameter_name').Clear` instead. If you want rows with empty blob fields to display `deleted`, do so in your SELECT statement when you're retrieving data to display.

Comment: Thanks, if you want put it as an answer and I can accept.

Comment: How does this relates to `[delphi]`? This is pretty much low quality `[sql]` question.

Comment: @tcsh, and so what? There is nothing specific to `[delphi]` there besides the `[ignorance]`. Please do some research first (yes, that fine manual).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clear the content of a blob field, assign it the value NULL.

```
dbmodule.arhivaQuery.SQL.Add('UPDATE `database_name`.`2nd_table_name` SET `column_name` = NULL WHERE `id`=''' + inttostr(dbmodule.comenziDataSetid.Value) + ''';');
```

If you want to display *deleted* for those columns that have no value, do that in your `SELECT` statement when retrieving the content using `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()`, whichever your DBMS supports.

An additional improvement you could make (both for coding ease and prevention of SQL injection) is to **stop** concatenating your SQL and switch to using parameters. It also means you can stop with all of the `'''` double/triple/quadruple quoting nonsense and data type conversions, because the DB driver will take care of all of that for you.

```
dbmodule.arhivaQuery.SQL.Add('UPDATE `database_name`.`2nd_table_name` SET `column_name` = NULL WHERE `id`= :ID;');
// Use AsInteger, AsString, AsFloat, or AsBoolean, whichever fits your
// column data type. Notice no quotes, no call to IntToStr or FloatToStr.
dbmodule.arhivaQuery.ParamByName('ID').AsString := dbmodule.comenziDataSetid.Value;
```

*NOTE:* Some DB drivers will need `Params.ParamByName` instead. If one doesn't work, the other will.

Finally, break your long lines of SQL into manageable pieces so you can stop all of the scrolling around to read it.

```
dbmodule.arhivaQuery.SQL.Add('UPDATE `database_name`.`2nd_table_name`');
dbmodule.arhivaQuery.SQL.Add('SET `column_name` = NULL WHERE `id`= :ID;');
dbmodule.arhivaQuery.ParamByName('ID').AsString := dbmodule.comenziDataSetid.Value;
```

Comment: "*If you want to display 'deleted' for those columns that have no value, ...*" - or, let the UI control that is displaying the data handle that instead.  Make it detect whether a NULL value is present or not and render itself accordingly.  Then you don't have to worry about it in the SQL itself.

Comment: "*Finally, break your long lines of SQL into manageable pieces ...*" - when using `SQL.Add()`, you should use `SQL.BeginUpdate()` and `SQL.EndUpdate()` to prevent the SQL engine from wasting overhead trying to process the SQL on each call to `Add()`.  Alternatively, use `SQL.Text` instead, with line breaks inserted between the SQL pieces, eg: `SQL.Text := 'UPDATE ...' + <line break> ' SET ...' + <line break> ' WHERE ...';` That way, you still get the readability in the code, and the SQL engine still sees only one update of the SQL statement.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Which is because SetText calls BeginUpdate/EndUpdate

Comment: @GerryColl well no, because `SetText()` triggers the `SQL.OnChange` event only once, whereas `SQL.Add` triggers `SQL.OnChange` each time, if `SQL.BeginUpdate` hasn't been called.